# Log in a devise user in different subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I have foo.local.host and bar.local.host and want to log in with a Devise user in app1 and have the same user logged also in app2 automatically.

I added this line to my foo/config/initializer/**session_store.rb**

```
foo::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_foo_session', domain: '.local.host'
```

And this line to my bar/config/initializer/**session_store.rb**

> bar::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,  domain:
>   '.local.host'

But if i login with a user in foo i got current_user nil in bar.
Is there any errors?